# react-native TextInput component not showing the http url value properly in the iPhone SE model

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput, react-native-text

In iPhone SE model, react-native TextInput component not display the http url properly. If I entered the value as `https://www.test.com` means it display the value only as `https://`
[Issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5wge.jpg)

But If I entered as `https://www.test.com/abc` it display as `https://www.test.com/` not showing `abc`

Problem is display the value only until the last slash exists.

```
import { TextInput } from "react-native";
        <TextInput
            {...props}
            value={value}
            editable={true}
            ref={ref => (setRef(ref))}
            onFocus={onFocus}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChangeText={handleChange}
            onEndEditing={handleEndEditing}
        />
```

Comment: Can you post the whole screen or at least the related functions? May be it is getting formatted somewhere else

Comment: Hi @SuyashVashishtha, I posted the code that I am trying, I verified in multiple iPhone models (iPhone 12, and iPhone 13)  it is working fine. but this particular iPhone SE model only fails.

Comment: hi @SuyashVashishtha , this formatting happens only http url otherwise it is working fine in the iPhone SE model. so it is not design issue.